# Prove that if $A \subseteq [0,\infty)$ and $B \subseteq (-\infty,0]$, then $\sup(AB) = \sup{B} \inf{A}$

Tags: calculus

> Prove that if $A \subseteq [0,\infty)$ and $B \subseteq (-\infty,0]$, then $\sup(AB) = \sup{B} \inf{A}$. Note: Assume $A,B$ are nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and define $\alpha A = \{\alpha A | a \in A\}$.

I don't believe this result is true. Firstly, let $B \subseteq [0,\infty)$ and $A$ as defined in question. Then $\sup(A \cdot -B) = \inf{A}\inf{-B} = -\inf{A}\sup{B}$, while on the other hand, $\sup{-B}\inf{A} = -\inf{B}\inf{A}$ which means that if both sides are equal then $\sup{B} = \inf{B}$, contradiction.

Comment: You have a _very_ low acceptance rate on your posts. I suggest that you go through your old posts and accept as many answers as you feel have accurately answered your questions. Leaving questions unanswered is very poor form as a user of this site as it causes questions which have acceptable answers to be bumped by Community unnecessarily.

Comment: @Puzzled417 Agreed. Please see what Cameron wrote.

Comment: Leaving questions without acceptances* Not sure where my head was on that one.

Comment: @Puzzled417 Can you justify your claim that $\sup(A\cdot -B) = \inf A \inf -B$?  $A$ is non-negative but $-B$ is non-positive.

Comment: @ErickWong Sorry, that's wrong what I have. What I meant was $\sup{A \cdot -B} = -\inf{A} \cdot \inf{B}$.

Comment: @Puzzled417 I believe you now have enough to answer your own question.  You can even accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $A,B \in [0,\infty)$. Then $\sup(A\cdot -B) = -\inf{A} \cdot \inf{B}$ while $\sup{-B} \inf{A} = -\inf{B} \inf{A}$, as desired.